# Unable to connect to MS SQL database using jdbc

Tags: jdbc

I'm trying to connect to my MS SQL 2008 database using jdbc as below but its giving error

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager
            .getConnection(
                    "jdbc:sqlserver://vermdbhqd01:1433;databaseName=irmreports",
                    "irm", "1234");
```

My database name is `irmreports` and Instance name is `irm_dev`. Please advise how can i provide both Database instance name and also database name in URL.

it says

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'irm'.
```

But when i try to login with same user name and password from DB GUI, it getting logged in. Wondering where to give details of database instance details in jdbc settings

I had also tried with below dut doesnt work

```
Connection con = DriverManager
.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://vermdbhqd01:1433;instanceName=IRM_DEV;databaseName=irmreports;user=irm;password=1234");
```

Comment: Are you actually using a username and password when connecting with the management studio, or are you using Windows authentication (integrated security)?

Comment: im usnig SQL authentication

Comment: managed to get it working using odbc connection but problem with jdbc 4 still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it working after removing the port details from connection string as below

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        Connection con = null;
        con = DriverManager
                .getConnection(

                "jdbc:sqlserver://vermdbhqd01;databaseName=irmreports;instanceName=irm_dev;selectMethod=cursor;user=irm;password=1234");
```

Comment: That would be a sign that you have multiple SQL server instances on your machine. If you specify a port number, then the specified `instanceName` is **ignored** and the driver connects to the instance running on the specified port.

Comment: Yes. You are Right. We have multiple instances running on SQL server and as you said, i think its Ignoring instanceName when port was mentioned. Sadly this was not mentioned in any Microsoft JDBC documentation :(